# Inverse functions - how are they calculated?

Tags: functions, inverse

*Mathematica* is able to calculate `InverseFunction[LogIntegral]` and `InverseFunction[RiemannR]` (and many other inverse functions). How are these calculated? (I can see how `LogIntegral` and `RiemannR` are calculated if I go to the details section of the docs, but can't find a ref. for inverse functions.)

Note: I have tried looking at `Series[LogIntegral[n], {n, 2, 3}]`, and `InverseSeries[Series[LogIntegral[n], {n, 2, 3}]]`, but can't see clearly how this helps.

Comment: I believe it uses numerical inversion in some cases.  `InverseFunction[LogIntegral][1]` gives a `Root` object in v9 which suggests it uses the technology described [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/18/mathematica-7-johannes-kepler-and-transcendental-roots/).

Comment: Great - thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could look at

```
Trace[InverseFunction[LogIntegral], TraceInternal -> True]
Trace[InverseFunction[RiemannR], TraceInternal -> True]
```

they both give huge outputs. Maybe try to filter out some patterns to limit the output. Especially part of evaluation having to do with messages would be nice to filter out.

Comment: Hmmmm, having looked at these, I am none the wiser I am afraid!!

Comment: @martin yes, I must agree it looks quite hopeless.

Answer (score -1):

Series on `RiemannR[x]` does not have  "good" Taylor expansion. Mathematica uses

```
Sum[MoebiusMu[n] LogIntegral[x^(1/n)]/n,{n,1,Infinity}]
```

which is also Ramanujan's series

```
RiemannR[x]-1 =Sum[Log[x]^n/(n n! Zeta[n+1]),{n,1,Infinity}]
```

A Classic Taylor expansion is numerically not stabile. You can to obtain at e.g. 2

```
Series[RiemannR[n], {n, 2, 5}] // Normal
```

which numerically is

```
1.54100901618713188328850378663 + 
 0.492873059153156128131756166775 (-2 + n) - 
 0.0357109244118073885987311878275 (-2 + n)^2 + 
 0.00842427070823529131964822281131 (-2 + n)^3 - 
 0.00256717021764032582595064954549 (-2 + n)^4 + 
 0.000885898743654821946805390294121 (-2 + n)^5
```

Generally Mathematica do not count directly `RiemannR[0]` or `RiemannR[-2]` but we can obtain these values by following trick:

Evaluate complex `RiemannR[-2+I x]` and count real part for very small x
but problem is numerically not stabile because in 0 is cusp (singularity)

The reversed Ramanujan series should contain `Sum[c[n] Exp[x]^n,{n,0,Infinity}]` where `c[n]` are constants.

Finally the reversed function `RiemannR[x]-1` as a Taylor series is

```
1+(Zeta[2])y+ 0.42722 y^2- 0.114811 y^3 +0.04736 y^4
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica! I have edited a bit of your answer, but perhaps you can more directly address the question (I think this is where you got the downvote). Do you mean inverse function when you talk about the "reversed" function? Perhaps edit the text here to make this clearer.